# Can't get my model out of wireframe mode in blender 2.59 after saved the blender file in newer version (blender 2.79)

Tags: wireframe, versions, draw-mode

I'm new to Blender and this site, so I apologize in advance if I'm not following any of the proper etiquette. I'm no artist, but I'm trying to learn Blender so that I can mod a skin to GTA:SA.

I need older version of blender to make my downloaded dff import/export add-on compatible, but I need newer version of blender too to be able to transfer weights between 2 objects.

The problem is even though the *Object->Display->Maximum Draw* is set to *Textured* in 2.79, there's no *Maximum Draw* dropdown in 2.59, and so the object is set to *Wire* with no way to change it in 2.59.

How can I solve this problem?

Blender 2.79:
[image: Blender 2.79]

Blender 2.59:
[image: Blender 2.59]

Comment: I'm not sure you can solve this. Blender is nearly always backwards compatible but not always forward compatible. New versions of blender sometimes come with a warning that opening and then saving older projects will result in the file no longer being compatible with the older version of Blender.

Comment: Yeah, I think so.
Thankfully I have the original .obj

Answer (score 2):

Maybe open the 2.59 .blend first in 2.60, then in 2.61, then in 2.62... and so on and save each time. You may skip a few if you're lucky :) (oh, in your case it might be the other way around, from 2.79 to 2.7 to 2.6... or like that, which may or may not work - but worth a try)

**[Here are the releases](https://download.blender.org/release/)**

Comment: oh god oh no...